# Avoiding cross-site scripting vulnerabilities in style with htmlSafe()

Tags: wordpress, ember.js, xss, advanced-custom-fields

Hej 
I am new(ish) to ember.js and am trying to build a helper function that processes string input from an ACF input field on wordpress. The attempt is to avoid getting a warning message from the browser about XSS attacks. Simply: the goal is to be able to create colors and gradient re-designs through the clients cms. 
However; even tho the string runs through the helper easily, and produces the desired effect of a new, supposedly safe, html string. I still get the warning.

code snippets are here:
from the helper in app/helpers

```
import {helper} from '@ember/component/helper'
import Ember from 'ember';
import { htmlSafe } from '@ember/string'
const htmlEscape = Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression;

export function escapeCSS(string) {
    let safestring = htmlEscape(string);    
    return htmlSafe(safestring);
}

export default helper(escapeCSS)
```

from the template

```
<div style="background-image:linear-gradient({{escapeCSS model.page.acf.top_color}}, {{escapeCSS model.page.acf.bottom_color}})" class="/homepage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good News! Someone has already written this. See https://github.com/romulomachado/ember-cli-string-helpers#html-safe

If you would like the helper to also escape your css, you can build upon it. The source code is here:

https://github.com/romulomachado/ember-cli-string-helpers/blob/master/addon/helpers/html-safe.js

I've made this all work:

```
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';
import { htmlSafe, isHTMLSafe } from '@ember/string';

function escapeCss([stringToEscape]) {
  let cssEscapedString = CSS.escape(stringToEscape);
  let htmlSafeString = htmlSafe(cssEscapedString);
  return htmlSafeString;
}

// copied from https://github.com/romulomachado/ember-cli-string-helpers/blob/master/addon/-private/create-string-helper.js

function wrapFunction(stringFunction) {
  return function([string]) {
    if (isHTMLSafe(string)) {
      string = string.string;
    }

    string = string || '';
    return stringFunction([string]);
  };
}

export default helper(wrapFunction(escapeCss));
```

You can see a demo here: https://ember-twiddle.com/19f3d8baa3fff404191d5ac3862355a9?openFiles=helpers.escape-css%5C.js%2C

Comment: Hej thank you so much for your help! I am still encountering a fatal error tho: the string returned from the helper is preluded with something my console.log interprets as a "/", but when i make into an html element, seems to be something more ike a round bracket. I have tried to continue the attempt to escapeCSS(input) for every single ACF input field, instead of concating entire style-strings, and it misunderstand the entire string because of this character. I will hardcode it out for a test, but that seems like a patch on a big leak

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically creating a `style` attribute is risky. Ember tries to avoid it. I'm not sure if marking the string as HTML will help in anyway. I recommend that you don't construct a `style` attribute yourself but set the CSS styles using CSSOM. [ember-style-modifier](https://github.com/jelhan/ember-style-modifier) provides a declarative way to do so.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the ember-style-modifier addon.